# IIS Developer Express on XP using Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, webserver

As of recently there is a **express edition of the IIS 7**. It is bundled with this crazy new tool Web Matrix (http://www.asp.net/webmatrix).

A real IIS instead of the development server in **Visual Studio** would have many advantages.

Does anybody know, if this IIS edition can be separately downloaded ?

Can it be installed on **Windows XP (Professional)** ? If yes, are there conflicts with the old **IIS 5.1** on XP ?

Can it be integrated in Visual Studio (2008, 2010)?

Answer (score 4):

- It will be released for download separately to the WebMatrix but as of yet it is only available as part of the WebMatrix bundle
- It can be used on XP SP3, it will not conflict with 5.1 as it runs as a self contained instance
- Yes, it can be integrated with VS2010 (you can tell VS to use IIS7 Express rather than Cassini)

Some useful links -

- [ScottGu addresses your first question and part of the integration work](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/28/introducing-iis-express.aspx)
- [The IIS7 Express FAQ](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/901/iis-developer-express-faq/) where your supported platform questions are answered (along with a whole lot more)